Ошибка при установке модуля curlify в python 3.11
Мне нужно установить curlify==2.2.1, но проблема в том, что при установке возникает ошибка. Полный процесс установки:
ERROR: Could not build wheels for curlify, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Collecting curlify==2.2.1
  Using cached curlify-2.2.1.tar.gz (3.0 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from curlify==2.2.1) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in ./.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->curlify==2.2.1) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->curlify==2.2.1) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in ./.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->curlify==2.2.1) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests->curlify==2.2.1) (2024.6.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: curlify
  Building wheel for curlify (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [42 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-aqfz1qu8/curlify_922d00eea7bc478e9610069934984927/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
          setup(
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 172, in setup
          ok = dist.parse_command_line()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 475, in parse_command_line
          args = self._parse_command_opts(parser, args)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 901, in _parse_command_opts
          nargs = _Distribution._parse_command_opts(self, parser, args)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 534, in _parse_command_opts
          cmd_class = self.get_command_class(command)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 748, in get_command_class
          self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 202, in load
          module = import_module(match.group('module'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 28, in <module>
          from .macosx_libfile import calculate_macosx_platform_tag
        File "PycharmProjects/сustomer/tests/Web.FunctionalTests/pytest/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/macosx_libfile.py", line 43, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for curlify
  Running setup.py clean for curlify
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
      
      error: option --all not recognized
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for curlify
Failed to build curlify
ERROR: Could not build wheels for curlify, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

В чём может быть проблема?

curlify не обновлялся с 2019 года, возможно просто не поддерживает Python 3.11. Пробуйте curlify2, он поновее, год назад релизился.

На другом компьютере с ОС Windows 11 всё установилось, версия python 3.11. На Linux Mint с той же версией выскакивает эта ошибка.

Ну, такое бывает. В любом случае пробуйте curlify2

А, ну еще попробуйте через apt установить пакеты python3.11-dev, python3.11-full

У меня на mint все прекрасно ставится: https://i.sstatic.net/MJvDdxpB.png, скорее всего действительно у вас python 3.11 в минимальной конфигурации установлен, поэтому см. комментарий выше

а можете для совсем чайника сами команды написать?)) Просто я второй день на линуксе и пока что очень тяжело

sudo apt install python3.11-dev, sudo apt install python3.11-full
